# read file content in for/while loop, removing escape characters

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm trying to read the contents of a file, that have line separators as `CRLF` but I think that is not a problem, and also have a character `\n` at the end of each line and sometimes a `\t` between words, is there a way I can read its content, one line at a time, but ignoring every escape character? I don't want to read the `\n` and `\t`, aI want to ignore them.

My file (`arq.txt`):

```
aaaaa\n
bbbbb\n
ccccc\n
ee\teee\n
ddddd\n
fffff\n
gg\tggg\n
hhhhh\n
```

What I've tried:

```
$ while IFs="" ; read line ; do echo $line ; done < arq.txt 
aaaaan
bbbbbn
cccccn
eeteeen
dddddn
fffffn
ggtgggn
hhhhhn
```

and:

```
$ for line in `cat arq.txt` ; do echo $line ; done
aaaaa\n
bbbbb\n
ccccc\n
ee\teee\n
ddddd\n
fffff\n
gg\tggg\n
hhhhh\n
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know a way to prevent the character sequences from being read at all, but you can use `read -r` to prevent them being treated as ANSI escapes, and then remove the literal `\t` and `\n` from the result:

```
$ while IFS= read -r line; do echo "${line//\\[tn]/}"; done < arq.txt 
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
eeeee
ddddd
fffff
ggggg
hhhhh
```

Note that you could achieve the same with external regex tools such as `sed 's/\\[tn]//g' arq.txt`

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('arq.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print (line.rstrip().replace('\t',''))
```

Paste that into a text file and save as `arq.py` in the same directory as your arq.txt file.

Run it with `python arq.py`

Explanation: 
Prints each line in the file. The `rstrip()` removes end-of-line characters. The `replace` replaces tab characters ('`\t`' is the escape sequence for the tab character) with empty strings.

Comment: Hi, even though I'd be using the "pure shell" approach in my ".sh", It's nice to know about this way, +1, thanks